# Maybe it's a question about the interface in python

Tags: python

I need help

I've run the sample code of [pygame](https://github.com/pygame/pygame) as follows.

```
# Example file showing a circle moving on screen
import pygame

# pygame setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
dt = 0

player_pos = pygame.Vector2(screen.get_width() / 2, screen.get_height() / 2)

while running:
    # poll for events
    # pygame.QUIT event means the user clicked X to close your window
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # fill the screen with a color to wipe away anything from last frame
    screen.fill("purple")

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, "red", player_pos, 40)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player_pos.y -= 300 * dt
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player_pos.y += 300 * dt
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_pos.x -= 300 * dt
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player_pos.x += 300 * dt

    # flip() the display to put your work on screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    # limits FPS to 60
    # dt is delta time in seconds since last frame, used for framerate-
    # independent physics.
    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000

pygame.quit()
```

As I looked at these codes, I wondered how they were implemented.

So I ctrl + left-clicked the get() part of pygame.event.get() and
get_pressed() part of pygame.key.get_pressed() on vs code

As a result, i found that get() in pygame.event.get() is defined in the file event.pyi, and get_pressed() in pygame.key.get_pressed() is defined in the file key.pyi

```
# event.pyi file

from typing import (
    Any,
    Dict,
    List,
    Optional,
    Sequence,
    SupportsInt,
    Tuple,
    Union,
    final,
    overload,
)

@final
class Event:
    type: int
    dict: Dict[str, Any]
    __dict__: Dict[str, Any]
    __hash__: None  # type: ignore
    def __init__(
        self, type: int, dict: Dict[str, Any] = ..., **kwargs: Any
    ) -> None: ...
    def __getattribute__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...
    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None: ...
    def __delattr__(self, name: str) -> None: ...
    def __bool__(self) -> bool: ...

_EventTypes = Union[SupportsInt, Tuple[SupportsInt, ...], Sequence[SupportsInt]]

def pump() -> None: ...
def get(
    eventtype: Optional[_EventTypes] = None,
    pump: Any = True,
    exclude: Optional[_EventTypes] = None,
) -> List[Event]: ...
def poll() -> Event: ...
def wait(timeout: int = 0) -> Event: ...
def peek(eventtype: Optional[_EventTypes] = None, pump: Any = True) -> bool: ...
def clear(eventtype: Optional[_EventTypes] = None, pump: Any = True) -> None: ...
def event_name(type: int) -> str: ...
def set_blocked(type: Optional[_EventTypes]) -> None: ...
def set_allowed(type: Optional[_EventTypes]) -> None: ...
def get_blocked(type: _EventTypes) -> bool: ...
def set_grab(grab: bool) -> None: ...
def get_grab() -> bool: ...
def set_keyboard_grab(grab: bool) -> None: ...
def get_keyboard_grab() -> bool: ...
def post(event: Event) -> bool: ...
def custom_type() -> int: ...

EventType = Event
```

```
# key.pyi file

from typing import Tuple

from ._common import RectValue

class ScancodeWrapper(Tuple[bool, ...]): ...

def get_focused() -> bool: ...
def get_pressed() -> ScancodeWrapper: ...
def get_mods() -> int: ...
def set_mods(mods: int) -> None: ...
def set_repeat(delay: int = 0, interval: int = 0) -> None: ...
def get_repeat() -> Tuple[int, int]: ...
def name(key: int, use_compat: bool = True) -> str: ...
def key_code(name: str) -> int: ...
def start_text_input() -> None: ...
def stop_text_input() -> None: ...
def set_text_input_rect(rect: RectValue) -> None: ...
```

**here is my question.
Where can I find the contents of the parts marked with ...?**

If this is an interface, shouldn't it be implemented somewhere?
but i cant find it.

i found definition of get() like following in fastevent.py

```
def get():
    """get() -> list of Events
    get all events from the queue
    """
    _ft_init_check()
    return pygame.event.get()
```

Did I find it right?

And one more,

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    running = False
```

QUIT is defined as QUIT: int in the file named constants.pyi

**Then, is it correct that the intention of this code is to end when the type of event is int?
Then, is the click of the exit button the only int type event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` as a function body usually means the function isn't implemented in Python. Usually it's implemented in C, the language in which the default Python interpreter is written. The most prominent reason to do this is performance. Similarly the variable `QUIT` does not have a value defined in Python.

Unimplemented functions and undefined variables may still have type signatures, like `int`, as these may be used by type checkers that only know about Python code. There isn't any meaningful relationship between `QUIT` and `int` at runtime; comparing something to `QUIT` is like any other equality comparison, and isn't a type check.

You can find the C implementation of Pygame on GitHub. The implementation of `event.get` is at https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/src_c/event.c#L2021.

Bear in mind that C and Python work differently and Pygame is a large library, so it may be hard to understand the implementation.